# I need to transfer point fron one user to another user

Tags: laravel

I need to transfer point from one user to another can anyone tell me how can I proceed with that.
I want to copy the point data that belong user A to user B. Firstly, i will get the user A's data.

Comment: Post your sample data. so that we can help u

Comment: Please add samples of what you have done and what you tried.
Also make a deeper explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume User A has 6points and you want to transfer it to user B with just 1 pathetic point.

```
$userB =User::where('email', 'b@mail.com')->first(); //get userB 
$userA =User::where('email', 'a@mail.com')->first(); //get userA 
//dont worry if you have these objects already.
//Now to transfer point

$userB->point =$userA->point;  //the transfer has happened;
$userB->update();
```